# AJAX can't work on Internet Explorer, but can be used on the other browsers

Tags: api, internet-explorer, axios

Lately playing with API, and run into some unknown problems. Even tried to figure it out on Internet but it doesn't work so l decided to post and ask for help.

When l was loading the website, api got launched. Api will put xxx in headers , on chrome,safari, Firefox will normally show it up, however IE 10 showed many problems

error showed that xxx doesn't exist in access-control-allow-headers but in the backend, xxx was added in access-control-allow-headers.
I used network to observe, chrome, safari and Firefox would have twice request. 
Once time is options, the other time is get. As for IE showed options only.

I took Ajax by the way l used axios, as follow

```
axios.get(URL, {
    headers: {
      'xxx': key
    }
})
.then(function(res) {
    // ...
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // ...
})
```

Guiqiu solution, thank you!